# Split File With positional value condition with awk

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file with the following structure :

```
<>aaaa01sdfgsfg 
<>aaaa02sfgsdfgs
<>aaaa02sgffsdgfs   
<>aaaa09sfgsdfgsdg   
<>aaaa01sdfgsfg 
<>aaaa02sfgsdfgs
<>aaaa02sgffsdgfs   
<>aaaa09sfgsdfgsdg
```

I would like to implement the following algorithm in awk:

```
cpt=0 
While Reading File 
Do
if Line(7-9) == 01 
cpt++
end if 
Writing Line in $FileName_$counter
Done
```

Thank you ! 
End

Comment: And what have you tried yet? How it faild? Did you read at least one awk tutorial? It's an easy task...

Comment: I implemented this in bash but with the command echo I have a problem with trim line. and I know that there is not this problem in awk. To be honest my awk skill is zero :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'substr($0,7,2) == "01" {c++} END {print FILENAME, c++}' FILENAME
```

might work for you.

Comment: awk '{if (substr($0,7,2) == "01") {c++;print >>FILENAME c} else print > FILENAME c}' FILENAME